# What's the best practice to retry when mysql write fails due to multi-process

Tags: mysql

2 different apps can access the same mysql db (don't ask me why).

Q1: i was told recent versions mysql does have internal write lock, so app itself doesn't need to have a lock on mysql write, is this true ?

Q2: if both apps are updating the same entry in db, 1 would failure if that entry is very big for whatever reason, timed out due to the 1st app didn't finish and release the lock. What's the best practice to handle this ? just retry the write again when fails ?

Comment: Of course it's true. All databases have concurrency protection. Otherwise they wouldn't be worthy of the name. Your second question is far too vague to be answerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i was told recent versions mysql does have internal write lock

Recent versions of MySQL (as in since 2010) use the [InnoDB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-introduction.html) storage engine, which supports transactions. Older versions are limited to the [MyISAM](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/myisam-storage-engine.html) engine, which does not.

It's possible that your installation is still running MyISAM, especially if your DBA / lead developer started working with MySQL before 2010 and thinks that it's "more performance." *Verify that you're running on InnoDB and convert if not.*

> if both apps are updating the same entry in db

The second will be blocked until the first either commits or rolls-back its transaction. Depending on how you've configured your connection, you may get a time-out on the second, but retrying it will just block again. You need to update the first to properly terminate its transactions.